# Pyrhon KeyError: 101 when I try to calculate multiple forecasts for a timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, forecasting

I want to use a time series in python and calculate n forecasts.
I tried to use a for cycle, but when I use n>=2 I get an error: "KeyError: 101"

I tried:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%YM%m')
df = pd.read_excel('test.csv', sheet_name=f'sheet_1', index_col=2, parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=dateparse)
ad = df['ad']
n = 2
k = 3
for x in range(n):
        tot = len(ad)-1
        adtf = 7 + 23*ad[tot-1] + 55*ad[tot-2] + 13*nu[tot-1] + 3*nu[tot-2]
        indexf = ad.index[tot]
        indexf += relativedelta(months=+1)
        i = pd.Index([indexf])
        ad = ad.append(pd.DataFrame({0:[adtf]}, index=i))
        nu = nu.append(pd.DataFrame({0:[k]}, index=i))
        print(ad)
```

PS: I have added `nu = nu.append(pd.DataFrame({0:[k]}, index=i))` in order to have a value to use in the next cyle.

Comment: could you show what `df` looks like? see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/6619250)

Comment: df is like:
`date,ad,nu

2010M01,12,23

2010M02,2,34`

note that in the code I forgot to write `nu = df['nu']` and that I wrote .csv instead of .xlsx.